# BMP2avi in python

Tags: python, bmp, avi

I am looking for a python code that takes series of BMP file and merges them into Avi file (and get the parameter frames per second from the user)

does anyone has an idea where to begin?

Ariel

Answer (score 0):

I'd begin by using [the GStreamer Python bindings](http://pygstdocs.berlios.de/pygst-tutorial/index.html); at a minimum, that'll take the AVI encoding (or [a great many other codecs, if you prefer](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/plugins.html)) off your plate.

It won't help with BMP input, though; either you can convert them to PNG or another natively-supported input format or use a different library such as PIL to decode them into a buffer for GStreamer's use (feeding the decoded buffers in with the appsrc plugin).